# Finding Duplicate Accounts

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm facing a problem with the data I've because of duplicate accounts, and I need to find all the duplicate accounts. For example

```
Main_account_number: XXXXXX | 
Duplicate_account_number: 00000XXXXXX.
```

Found some duplicate account like this with 0's as the prefix.

I tried framing an SQL using a subquery but that is not working

```
select acct_num,
       (select acct_num
        from account_table
        where acct_num like '0000%'+X.acct_num) as dup_acct
from account_table as X;
```

expected:

```
acct_num|dup_acct
123455  |0000123455
455585  |000045585
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean?

Comment: Sorry @GordonLinoff not working means our DBAs said subqueries might block the session, so they didn't approve it to run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
select a.acct_num, a2.acct_num as duplicate_acct_num
from account_table a join
     account_table a2
     on a2.acct_num = concat('0000', a.acct_num);
```

Or, if the number of `0`s can vary:

```
     on a2.acct_num regexp concat('^0+',  a.acct_num, '$');
```

Comment: Thanks to you, I don't know how I forgot using a join simply. let me try

Comment: first one worked fine for me thanks.
second line using regex errored out as invalid somehow